# Alphabetical sorter not working

Tags: java, sorting

I am writing a program that alphabetically sorts names entered by the user through `stdin`. The names are being picked up correctly, however the sorting isn't working. Could someone please assist me to work out why.

This is my code...

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){
            String names = StdIn.readString();
            String [] name = new String[1]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                name[i] = names;
            }

            Arrays.sort(name);

            for (int i = 0;  i < 1; i ++){
                System.out.println(name[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try printing `name[i]` and not `name[1]`

Comment: You're creating an array of 1. Sorting your list of 1. And printing it out immediately. Then, repeating the entire process over again. I don't see how it would work

Comment: (i.e.) there's nothing to sort, EVER if there's only 1 item in your array

Comment: Your array only holds one element, whatever you put in there is already sorted.

Comment: (a) pick a number of names to sort (b) allocate array for it (c) prompt user to 'enter <n> names' (d) sort it (e) display it.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say this isn't your real code, and when you have more than one name, you're seeing things like all strings starting with a capital letter coming before all strings starting with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious problems with the code mentioned in the comments, I would not use arrays. Instead, use a `java.util.Collection` implementation such as `java.util.TreeSet<String>` which is automatically sorted.